# Driver for Monitor Acer G205H for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, display

Is there anyway I can obtain the driver for monitor acer G205H? My machine is a Windows XP 32 bit machine.

I stumbled upon this website which claimed to have this driver, when I clicked on [the download link](http://driversdot.com/monitor/monitor-acer/gseries/524-g205h.html), I was asked to pay. But *drivers* are supposed to be free?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the driver you can download from http://acer.com, after selecting a country (I selected US, don't think it matters), *Service and Support*, *Driver Downloads*, *Monitors*, *G Series*, *G205H*, *G205H*?

The site says it only has drivers for Vista and 7, but the downloaded `.inf` file states:

```
;================================ 
; ACER_G205H.INF 08/06/09 Ver. 1.0 
; INF File for Windows 7/Vista/XP/Me/9x/2000
; Copyright (c) 2009, ACER Corporation
;================================
```

Comment: @Daniel, it is not an installer at all.

Comment: @Ngu Soo Hui: True. It's an [inf file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INF_file). The only thing it does is tell your system the native resolution and perhaps (don't remember) to use the bundles color profile. What else do you need?

Comment: @Daniel, I need a driver exe that installs-- not an autorun file

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Can't you manually add a device and specify the .inf file from System (or Hardware?) entry of Control Panel?

Comment: @Daniel, you have link on how to do this exactly?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: It's been 5 years since I really used Windows, so this might not work. Try `Control Panel`, `Add hardware`, `Add new hardware device` (bottom), `Advanced`, `Show all devices`, `Have disk`. Specify the `.inf` file.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Why do you need a driver, anyway? The screen should be able to tell your system its native resolution, and what else is there to do?

Comment: @Daniel, because i suspect that the monitor driver ( or lack of) was causing my computer to hang all the time, that's why I want to reinstall it

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Default drivers are good, they don't crash. And read the .inf file yourself, there's nothing in there but the display's native resolution. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui Did it work? (4 comments up I described the procedure)